# Strapi framework: can't get my page rendered

Tags: koa, strapi

I'm starting to play with Strapi framework and tried to use Handlebars and routes to show a page. I followed the docs and I created a controller with this:

```
find: function *() {
    try {
      yield this.render('user', {
            firstname: 'John',
            lastname: 'Doe'
        });
    } catch (error) {
      this.body = error;
    }
  },
```

and a router file with this:

```
 {
    "routes": {
      "GET /": {
        "controller": "strap",
        "action": "find"
      }
    }
  }
```

It is working (no errors) but I get a 404 not found status and not my page that is in `views/user.html` as in the docs.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... Your controller and route look good.

Make sure your config looks like this:

```
{
  "views": {
    "map": {
      "html": "handlebars"
    },
    "default": "html"
  }
}
```

You don't need to specify the file extension in your controller only if you have a `default` mapping key in your config. Otherwise you need to specify the extension like this:

```
find: function *() {
  try {
    yield this.render('user.html', {
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Doe'
    });
  } catch (error) {
    this.body = error;
  }
},
```

In your HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Firstname: {{ firstname }}<br>Lastname: {{ lastname }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, everything is just like that.

Comment: I found it! I had prefixed my `api` in the config file with the same name I had given to the `<apiname>` in the: `./api/<apiName>/config/routes.json`.

Comment: Oh I see. We'll try to improve this part of the documentation. Feel free to help us if you have any suggestions regarding the documentation: https://github.com/wistityhq/strapi-docs. We'd be glad to merge your improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it might be a conflict between your API routes and your public assets. Can you try to remove the `./public/index.html` file?